# Core Data in-memory saving

Tags: core-data

I am building an app which uses a `TabBarController` and has multiple views showing the SAME data, but in different ways. One of the views is a TableView and the other is a Map view.

The data comes from a server and I would like to have a way to store this data in which it is accessible from multiple view controllers (have a "single source of truth"). I believe that Core Data is a good choice, especially because I find the `NSFetchedResultsController` class rather convenient to work with when dealing with table views.

The data only needs to be around while the app is being used, so I am thinking about using Core Data without actually saving anything to the disk. I saw that there exists an `In-memory` store type which I believe is what I need. However, I found that just by inserting a new entity into my context (not yet calling `context.save()`), the `NSFetchedResultsController` can already detect the changes and update my UI.

**Question 1:** 
Is it really neccessary to call `context.save()` when using the `In-memory` store type?

*I believe it might be necessary in the case of multiple contexts.*

**Question 2:** 
If it is not necessary to call `context.save()`, does it even matter what persistent store type I use?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> Question 1: Is it really neccessary to call context.save() when using the In-memory store type?
>
> I believe it might be necessary in the case of multiple contexts.

That's correct. If you use the common pattern of having one context for the UI and a different one to handle incoming network data, you'll need to save changes for updates from one context to be available in the other.

> Question 2: If it is not necessary to call context.save(), does it even matter what persistent store type I use?

If you use an in-memory store, your persistent store type is `NSInMemoryStoreType`. It matters in that choosing the right store type is how you get it to be an in-memory store.

Keep in mind that using an in-memory store means that users won't be able to use the app offline in any way. Whether that's important depends on your app, but it can be useful to let people view older data when they don't have a network connection.